# Age group categorization

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe, in that I have age column.I want to apply user defined function, so it arrange age in bins. I have following function trying to apply over columns but i am getting error. Name of the column is 'age'

```
def ageGroup(x):
    if (data_drop_row['age'] > 0) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 10):
        return '1'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 10) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 20):
        return '2'
    elif( data_drop_row['age']) > 20 & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 30):
        return '3'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 30) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 40):
        return '4'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 40) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 50):
        return  '5'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 50) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 60):
        return  '6'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 60) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 70):
        return '7'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 70) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 80):
        return '8'
    elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 80) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 90):
        return '9'
    else:
        return '10'

data_drop_row['age_cat'] = data_drop_row['age'].apply(ageGroup)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-bc9d37e55aa8> in <module>
----> 1 data_drop_row['age_cat'] = data_drop_row['age'].apply(ageGroup)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3589             else:
   3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3592 
   3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-65-c5584bcb554d> in ageGroup(x)
      1 def ageGroup(x):
----> 2     if (data_drop_row['age'] > 0) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 10):
      3         return '1'
      4     elif (data_drop_row['age'] > 10) & (data_drop_row['age'] <= 20):
      5         return '2'

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1476         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
   1477                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
-> 1478                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
   1479 
   1480     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

can someone help on this

Comment: You are comparing a column with single value

Comment: i tried below method as well, i don't know where i am doing mistake.f ageGroup(x):
    if (age > 0) & (age <= 10):
        return '1'
    elif (age> 10) & (age <= 20):
        return '2'
    elif (age > 20 ) & (age <= 30):
        return '3'
    elif (age > 30) & (age <= 40):
        return '4'
    elif (age > 40) & (age <= 50):
        return '5'
    elif (age > 50) & (age <= 60):
        return '6'
     data_drop_row['age'] = data_drop_row['age'].apply(ageGroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buckets = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
buckets_name = ['1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

data_drop_row['age_cat']=pd.cut(data_drop_row['age'].values, buckets , labels = buckets_name)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help